# UTF-8 decoding error when querying Snowflake sample data with Snowflake Python connector

Tags: python, utf-8, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm getting an UTF-8 decoding error when querying one of the tables in the `SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA` database, which Snowflake provides when signing up for a trial account.

```py
import snowflake.connector
c = snowflake.connector.connect(..., database='SNOWFLAKE_SAMPLE_DATA')

r = c.cursor().execute("""
    SELECT tpcds_sf100tcl.customer.c_birth_country
    FROM tpcds_sf100tcl.customer WHERE c_birth_country LIKE 'R%'
    LIMIT 25 OFFSET 50
    """)
list(r)
```

**Exception**:

```
arrow_result.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_result.ArrowResult.__next__()

arrow_iterator.pyx in snowflake.connector.arrow_iterator.PyArrowIterator.__next__()

~/[...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in errorhandler_wrapper(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    121         if cursor is not None:
    122             cursor.messages.append((error_class, error_value))
--> 123             cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
    124             return
    125         elif connection is not None:

~/[...]/lib/python3.7/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py in default_errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
     86             sqlstate=error_value.get('sqlstate'),
     87             sfqid=error_value.get('sfqid'),
---> 88             done_format_msg=error_value.get('done_format_msg'))
     89
     90     @staticmethod

InterfaceError: 252005: Failed to convert current row, cause: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc9 in position 1: invalid continuation byte
```

This happens *only* when the result contains values with accented characters.

As far as I could find, Snowflake only supports UTF-8, so I find this strange.

Comment: Snowflake does have the ability to load non-UTF8 data (or ignore the check on the COPY INTO command), so is it possible that somebody loaded non-UTF8 data in that manner?  If so, you'll likely have these sorts of issues, which is why Snowflake doesn't recommend doing that.

Comment: I've checked and can confirm: the sample data provided by Snowflake (at least in this table/column) is not in UTF8
@MikeWalton Can Snowflake fix this?

Comment: @MikeWalton Thanks. This issue happens with data provided by Snowflake (sample datasets).

Answer (score 1):

We had similar issues in our downstream applications. They were not able to load the data due to non-UTF8 characters. We have created a javascript UDF in snowflake to replace the Non-UTF8 character from a string with the user provided replacement character and using this UDF function in our Load scripts. This way we are getting rid of all the Non-UTF8 characters from our snowflake table and also our downstream applications were able to load this data without any issues.

You can avoid this issue by excluding the Non-UTF8 records with below sql Statement :

```
SELECT tpcds_sf100tcl.customer.c_birth_country
    FROM tpcds_sf100tcl.customer WHERE c_birth_country LIKE 'R%'
    AND TRY_HEX_DECODE_STRING(HEX_ENCODE(c_birth_country)) IS NOT NULL
    LIMIT 25 OFFSET 50;
```